# Where's the mistake? Integral of a bounded non-analytic function over a closed curve.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Let $f(z)$ be a bounded non-analytic function defined on a closed curve $\gamma$. What is wrong with the following:

$$\left| \oint_\gamma f(z) dz\right| \le  \oint_\gamma \left|f(z) \right| dz \le M \oint_\gamma 1 \cdot dz =0$$

because $1$ is analytic on $\gamma$.

Of course when one writes

$$\left| \oint_\gamma f(z) dz \right| = \left| \int_a^b f(z(t)) z'(t)dt \right| \le \int_a^b  \left|  f(z(t)) z'(t) \right| dt  \le M \int_a^b|z'(t)|dt=M|\gamma|.$$

it works out as it should. What's wrong with the first one then? Which step is illegal?

Comment: $$\left| \oint_\gamma f(z) dz\right| \le  \oint_\gamma \left|f(z) \right| |dz|.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dz$ is a complex measure/differential form (whichever interpretation you prefer), so $$\oint_\gamma \lvert f(z)\rvert\,dz$$ is in general not real, hence the inequality doesn't make sense.

You get $$\left\lvert\oint_\gamma f(z)\,dz\right\rvert \leqslant \oint_\gamma \lvert f(z)\rvert\, \lvert dz\rvert,$$

where $\lvert dz\rvert$ is the total variation of $dz$ in the measure interpretation, which is realised by $\lvert z'(t)\rvert\,dt$.